# Loop through a tm corpus without losing corpus structure

Tags: r, for-loop, tm

I have a tm corpus of documents and a list of words. I want to run a `for` loop over the corpus, so that the loop removes each word in the list from the corpus sequentially.

Some replication data:

```
library(tm)
m <- cbind(c("Apple blue two","Pear yellow five","Banana yellow two"),
             c(1, 2, 3))
tm_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(m[,1]))
words <- as.list(c("Apple", "yellow", "two"))
```

`tm_corpus` is now a corpus object consisting of 3 documents:

```
<<SimpleCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 1, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 3
```

`words` is a list of 3 words:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Apple"

[[2]]
[1] "yellow"

[[3]]
[1] "two"
```

I have tried three different loops. The first one is:

```
tm_corpusClean <- tm_corpus
for (i in seq_along(tm_corpusClean)) {
  for (u in seq_along(words)) {
    tm_corpusClean[i] <- tm_map(tm_corpusClean[i], removeWords, words[[u]])
  }
}
```

Which returns the following error 7 times (numbered 1-7):

```
Error in x$dmeta[i, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In tm_corpusClean[i] <- tm_map(tm_corpusClean[i], removeWords,                 
words[[u]]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In tm_corpusClean[i] <- tm_map(tm_corpusClean[i], removeWords,         
words[[u]]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
[...]
```

The second one is:

```
tm_corpusClean <- tm_corpus
for (i in seq_along(words)) {
  for (u in seq_along(tm_corpusClean)) {
    tm_corpusClean[u] <- tm_map(tm_corpusClean[u], removeWords, words[[i]])
  }
}
```

Which returns the error:

```
Error in x$dmeta[i, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

The last loop is:

```
tm_corpusClean <- tm_corpus
for (i in seq_along(words)) {
  tm_corpusClean <- tm_map(tm_corpusClean, removeWords, words[[i]])
}
```

This actually returns an object named `tm_corpusClean`, but this object only returns the first document instead of all original three:

```
inspect(tm_corpusClean[[1]])

<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 6

 blue
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we go to the sequential removal, test if `tm_map` work on your example:

```
obj1 <- tm_map(tm_corpus, removeWords, unlist(words))
sapply(obj1, `[`, "content")

$`1.content`
[1] " blue "

$`2.content`
[1] "Pear  five"

$`3.content`
[1] "Banana  "
```

Next, use lapply to sequentially remove one word at a time, i.e. `"Apple", "yellow", "two"`:

```
obj2 <- lapply(words, function(word) tm_map(tm_corpus, removeWords, word))
sapply(obj2, function(x) sapply(x, `[`, "content"))

          [,1]                [,2]             [,3]              
1.content " blue two"         "Apple blue two" "Apple blue "     
2.content "Pear yellow five"  "Pear  five"     "Pear yellow five"
3.content "Banana yellow two" "Banana  two"    "Banana yellow "
```

Note that the resultant corpus are in a nested-list (reason why two sapply were used to view the content).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for answering. Your code works, but gives me NA's instead of the output you present here:  
  
    `obj1 <- tm_map(tm_corpus, removeWords, unlist(words))  
    sapply(obj1, `[`, "content")`  
  
    `[1] NA NA NA  
    
    obj2 <- lapply(words, function(word) tm_map(tm_corpus, 
    removeWords, word))  
    sapply(obj2, function(x) sapply(x, `[`, "content"))  
          
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  
    [1,] NA   NA   NA  
    [2,] NA   NA   NA  
    [3,] NA   NA   NA`

Sorry, can't figure out how to add line breaks.

Comment: For `obj1 <- tm_map(tm_corpus, removeWords, unlist(words))`, if you were to check `obj1[[1]]$content`, what did you get?

Comment: `obj1[[1]]$content` does return `[1] " blue "`, so the NA's only appear after running `sapply(obj1, `[`, "content")`, giving `[1] NA NA NA`. But it seems to have worked on the corpus itself. :)

Comment: That's odd. The `\`[\`` is supposed to be the equivalent of `$`