# Unlisting Corpus from TM package giving NA's

Tags: r, tm

I have a corpus I created using the TM package where I've applied all my transformations and am ready to convert it back to a data frame.

When I use

```
twit[[1]]$content
```

I can see my data.  However when I try to unlist it I get NA's for all my records.

```
twitCln <- data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(twit, '[', "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The linked question [Loop through a tm corpus without losing corpus structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604838/loop-through-a-tm-corpus-without-losing-corpus-structure) has a discussion after the only answer that has the same issue but there does not appear to be a resolution.

Here is some reproducible code.

```
library(tm)
bbTwit <- as.data.frame(c("Text Line One!", "Text Line 2"), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(bbTwit) <- 'Contents'
bbTwit$doc_id <- row.names(bbTwit) 
twit <- bbTwit[c('doc_id','Contents')]
colnames(twit) <- c('doc_id','text')

twit <-Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(twit)))
twit <-tm_map(twit, removePunctuation)
twit <-tm_map(twit, stripWhitespace)

twit[[1]]$content

twitCln <- data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(twit, '[', "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The expected output would be a data frame with 2 observations where "Text Line One" would be the first record and "Text Line 2" would be the second.  What I get is two observations of NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content out, just use the `content()` function. For example

```
content(twit)
# [1] "Text Line One" "Text Line 2"
```

or put it in a data.frame

```
data.frame(text=content(twit))
#            text
# 1 Text Line One
# 2   Text Line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the desired output it sounds like you want

```
mydf <- data.frame(unlist(twit)[1:(length(unlist(twit))-1)])
```

> ```
> content1                              Text Line One
> content2                                Text Line 2
> ```

where the row/column names can of course be set to whatever you like with `names()`.

or for a simple case:

```
rbind(twit[[1]]$content,
           twit[[2]]$content)
```

> ```
> [1,] "Text Line One"
> [2,] "Text Line 2"
> ```

e.g.

```
mydf <- data.frame(rbind(twit[[1]]$content,
                 twit[[2]]$content)
)
colnames(mydf) <- "Pretty Column"
mydf
```

> ```
>     Pretty Column
> 1   Text Line One
> 2   Text Line 2
> ```

Comment: The simultaneous edit nailed it.  Thank you very much.